# "Server Tag Not Well Formed" error in Validation Control

Tags: asp.net, validation-controls

I got this error when I placed the unique id of the control in the source code. Below is the source code.

```
<ucPopupMember:PopupMember ID="PopupMember_MemberID" 
                           runat="server"                                
                           TextBoxMaxLength="12"
                           ValidationGroup="SpkrSetupGroup"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_MemberID" 
                            runat="server" 
                            ErrorMessage="Member ID is required"
                            Text="*"
                            CssClass="errorlabel"
                            ValidationGroup="SpkrSetupGroup"
                            Display="Dynamic"
                            ControlToValidate="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder_MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel_Entry$PopupMember_MemberID$TextBox_MemberCode"/>
```

How to I change this or fix this? I'm having problems because of the "$" sign.

[UPDATE] The control to validate (textbox) is inside the user control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the "server" ID of the control for the [ControlToValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate.aspx) property. Both controls need to exist in the same container.

In the PopupMember control add the validator there:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_MemberID" 
                            runat="server" 
                            ErrorMessage="Member ID is required"
                            Text="*"
                            CssClass="errorlabel"
                            ValidationGroup="SpkrSetupGroup"
                            Display="Dynamic"
                            ControlToValidate="MemberCode"/>
```

I suppose the member code is always required so you don't have to anything more.

But if the MemberCode sometimes is not required, add a property in the code behind of the PopupMember control.

```
public bool MemberRequired
{
   set {RequiredFieldValidator_MemberID.Visible = value;}
}
```

By default is required. If you don't need it required by default use in markup `Visible="false"`

Comment: Hi Adrian! I updated the issue here. I forgot to add that the control which I want to validate is inside the user control.

Comment: You can't. The validator needs to be in that user control. Move the validator there, create a new boolean property named "Required" which sets the visibility of the validator.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what @Adrian suggested, I think the Beginning and Ending should look like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```